# Trying to add event listener to collection (or model) using "on" function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I'm trying to add an event to a collection. I want to re-render the view every time the collection changes (new model, model attribute changes, etc). Here is my code:

```
var app = {}; // custom name space

// models

app.Group = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '/group'
});
app.Category = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '/category'
});


// collections

app.GroupList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.Group,
    url: 'data/getGroups.php' // '/groups'
});

app.CategoryList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.Category,
    url: 'data/getCategories.php' // '/categories'
});

app.groupList = new app.GroupList();
app.categoryList = new app.CategoryList();


// views
app.CategoriesView = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...
});

// bind events
app.GroupList.on('change reset add remove', app.CategoriesView.render);
app.CategoryList.on('change reset add remove', app.CategoriesView.render);
```

...but, I get the following error in the console "TypeError: app.GroupList.on is not a function". I've tried doing the same for the model instead of the collection but same error - ".on" is not a function. In the documentation it seems "on" belongs to models at least but as mentioned this didn't work either. How is the correct way to add a listener? should I be doing so on the model or the collection?

If anyone can offer any help it would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can only bind events to *instances*:

```
app.groupList.on(...);
```

In the same vein, `render` is only for a view instance:

```
// views
app.CategoriesView = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...
});

var myView = new app.CategoriesView({
   // somewhere in here you'll pass app.grouplist...
});

app.groupList.on('change reset add remove', myView.render);
```